# Using Selenium in a maven project

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dependencies

I created a MavenTestProject in Eclipse with these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now my maven dependencies folder contains drivers for these browsers:

[image: Maven dependencies]

What are these libraries for? Can I just use them? Or do I still need to download other .exe files to use the drivers like mentioned in other posts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the ChromeDriver.exe when you execute your testcase on Chrome, the ChromeDriver.exe accept the command from Selenium and then communicate with Chrome browser. so you need to download the exe files.